# how can i know on which git branch I am when I do git clone from dockerfile

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

My dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipeline@script/xxxxx
RUN apt-get -y install git
RUN git clone https://Team:1234@bitbucket.org/MinoxTeam/xxxxx.git /xxxxx && \
    cd /xxxxx
```

I am using these commands from jenkinsfile in order to confirm that I am on master and I have updated master branch and only then i run tests:

```
pipeline {
 stage {
  steps {
    checkout scm 
    sh 'git checkout master'
    sh 'git pull'`enter code here`
    sh 'npm i'
    sh 'npm run test:single rest'
  }
 }
}
```

my question is when i do git clone from my dockerfile itself it already get the workspace along with the docker image, so do i have to do checkout scm and git checkout master - is it not automatically on master ?

**I dont want to depend on jenkins gui for checkout step from piplelineSCM**

Comment: You should probably just use the git tree Jenkins is already creating in the `checkout scm` step and not try to do a clone in the Dockerfile.  This avoids potentially leaking credentials and means your image will be for the actual commit Jenkins is building, which may not be the head of master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line you can get the branch in any bash with the git and perl command available (perl is usually everywhere).

```
#outputs: master
git status -b --porcelain | perl -ne 'print $1 if /## (\w+)/'
```

This line can be integrated on other scripts, as it outputs only the branch name. Run it after cloning or execute simply `git status` to show human readable info.

Comment: i get this out when i have git status in docker file  ---> Running in 80f4ee136fb4
Cloning into '/xxxxx
Removing intermediate container 80f4ee136fb4
 ---> 74d28571debb
Step 7/31 : RUN git status
 ---> Running in 2239d0bf60e6
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/jenkins_home)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins defines a GIT_BRANCH environment variable. You can add this step to check it:

```
sh "echo ${env.GIT_BRANCH}"
```